# Native class limiting

Tags: team-fortress-2

I remember someday it became possible to limit classes on tf2 server without using plugins, but now I cannot find any reference for that.

Any hints variable names for class limiting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, but it might not be the kind of class limiting you're looking for:

```
sv_highlander 1
```

...makes it so you can only have one of each class; it's only useful for Highlander 9v9 matches obviously.

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I need... I want to limit snipers and spys to 1 per team for example, everything else is unrestricted.

Comment: @BarsMonster Yeah, I'm afraid you're going to need mods for that.

Comment: Can anyone post a link to one of those mods? I still feel like this question hasn't been fully answered.

Comment: @Aceofgods Drake came to the rescue! http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/60983/23

Comment: Highlander sure must make Spy difficult

Answer (score 3):

As already answered by badp there is no way to fine-tune class limits without mods.

If you have no problems to install mods on your server, you can check these two:

- [TF2 Class Restrictions](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=73104)
- [TF2 Class Limit](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=62630)

More generally speaking always take a look to [AlliedModders Forum](http://forums.alliedmods.net/forumdisplay.php?f=123) when you need some plugin for TF2, it is one of the best resource out there.

Comment: Yep, this is what I had to do, it works.